# Add a checkbox to most parent tree element?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to add a checkbox widget to the most upper parent tree element like shown in http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_checkbox

How could I do this by just using GWT?
I only found that I can create a Tree*Item* with a checkbox and add it to the Tree:

```
TreeItem item = new TreeItem(new CheckBox("box"));
```

But how can I create a box for the Tree itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assemble your own widget  that extends gwt Composite class and wrap in it a tree/celltree , flowpanels and any widget you like to add like a select all checkbox.

You should be trying to  use cell widget based **CellTree** - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree

It is much more customizable and ensures better performance.